# Grep Filenames from ls for specific part of them

Tags: grep

I want to extract a specific part out of the filenames to work with them.
Example:

```
ls -1

REZ-Name1,Surname1-02-04-2012.png
REZ-Name2,Surname2-07-08-2013.png
....
```

So I want to get only the part with the name.
How can this be achieved ?

Comment: Do you want to use `grep` and `ls` even though those are not the right tools for the job?

Comment: @thatotherguy So tell me better tools than sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Here's a loop:

```
for file in REZ-*-??-??-????.png
do
  name=${file#*-}
  name=${name%-??-??-????.png}
  echo "($name)"
done
```

Given a variety of filenames with all sorts of edge cases from spacing, additional hyphens and line feeds:

```
REZ-Anna-Maria,de-la-Cruz-12-32-2015.png
REZ-Bjørn,Dæhlie-01-01-2015.png
REZ-First,Last-12-32-2015.png
REZ-John Quincy,Adams-11-12-2014.png
REZ-Ridiculous example                            # this is one filename
is ridiculous,but fun-22-11-2000.png              # spanning two lines
```

it outputs:

```
(Anna-Maria,de-la-Cruz)
(Bjørn,Dæhlie)
(First,Last)
(John Quincy,Adams)
(Ridiculous example
is ridiculous,but fun)
```

If you're less concerned with correctness, you can simplify it further:

```
$ ls | grep -o '[^-]*,[^-]*'
Maria,de
Bjørn,Dæhlie
First,Last
John Quincy,Adams
is ridiculous,but fun
```

Comment: This would be a solution but I'm looking for a way to do it with some easy commands maybe with a pipe for example like this : `grep ...... | ls -1`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, cut makes more sense than grep:

```
ls -l | cut -f2 -d-
```

cut the second field from the input, using '-' as the field delimiter.  That other guy's answer will correctly handle some cases mine will not, but for one off uses, I generally find the semantics of cut to be much easier to remember.